# Get qty of products in an order UNIQUE

Tags: magento

I have a order with 3 items: 1º product x 1 qnt 2º product x 2 qnt 3º product x 1 qnt

if i use:

```
$_order = $this->getOrder();
foreach ($_order->getAllItems() as $items){
$qnttotal = $items->getQtyOrdered();
```

result in 1.

if i use:

```
$_order = $this->getOrder();
foreach ($_order->getAllItems() as $items){
$qty = $items->getQty();
}
```

result in: "NULL".

How do I return me 3 (total of products)? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get total qty from order object directly no need of iteration.

Please check below code:

```
$_order = $this->getOrder();
echo 'Total qty is '.$_order->getTotalQtyOrdered();
```

And if you want total item ordered tha please check below code:

```
$_order = $this->getOrder();
echo 'Total Item is '.$_order->getTotalItemCount();
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: can i get mysql query?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for total line items;

```
$count = 0;
$_order = $this->getOrder();

foreach ($_order->getAllItems() as $items){
   $count++
}

echo 'Total lines is '.$count;
```

Or this for total qty;

```
$totalqty = 0;
$_order = $this->getOrder();

foreach ($_order->getAllItems() as $items){
   $totalqty = $totalqty + $items->getQtyOrdered();
}

echo 'Total qty is '.$totalqty;
```

Comment: glad it helped!, please mark my response as the answer to close this.  Cheers.

Comment: can i get mysql query?